Movit launch file for ur5e with 2f-85 gripper
I am trying to create a launch file for launching moveit2 with ur5e robot and Robotiq 2f-85 gripper.
I know that .robot_decription requires file location but I need to pass ur_description launch arguments.
However, I am getting these errors, any insights would be helpful.
[INFO] [launch]: All log files can be found below /home/robotik/.ros/log/2024-11-13-11-46-48-627360-robotik-ThinkPad-P14s-Gen-2i-22260
[INFO] [launch]: Default logging verbosity is set to INFO
WARNING:root:Cannot infer URDF from /home/robotik/workspace/ros_ur_driver/install/ur_moveit_config/share/ur_moveit_config. -- using config/ur5e.urdf
WARNING:root:Cannot infer SRDF from /home/robotik/workspace/ros_ur_driver/install/ur_moveit_config/share/ur_moveit_config. -- using config/ur5e.srdf
[ERROR] [launch]: Caught exception in launch (see debug for traceback): Caught multiple exceptions when trying to load file of format [py]:

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'PosixPath' and 'ParameterValue'
InvalidFrontendLaunchFileError: The launch file may have a syntax error, or its format is unknown

'''
from launch import LaunchDescription
from launch.actions import DeclareLaunchArgument
from launch.substitutions import LaunchConfiguration, Command
from moveit_configs_utils import MoveItConfigsBuilder
import os
from launch_ros.actions import Node
from ament_index_python.packages import 
get_package_share_directory
from launch_ros.parameter_descriptions import ParameterValue

def generate_launch_description():
# Define file path for the URDF Xacro
urdf_xacro_file = os.path.join('/home/robotik/workspace/ros_ur_driver/src/Universal_Robots_ROS2_Description/urdf',
    'ur_2f-85.urdf.xacro')


# Declare arguments for .xacro file parameters
robot_ip_arg = DeclareLaunchArgument('robot_ip', default_value='192.168.1.102', description='IP address of the robot')
name_arg = DeclareLaunchArgument('name', default_value='ur5e', description='Robot name')
ur_type_arg = DeclareLaunchArgument('ur_type', default_value='ur5e', description='Type of the robot')
safety_limits_arg = DeclareLaunchArgument('safety_limits', default_value='true', description='Safety limits enabled')
tf_prefix_arg = DeclareLaunchArgument('tf_prefix', default_value='', description='TF prefix')

# Declare other arguments
is_sim_arg = DeclareLaunchArgument("is_sim", default_value="True", description="Flag to enable simulation time")
is_sim = LaunchConfiguration("is_sim")

# Define robot description from .xacro file with parameters
robot_description_arg = ParameterValue(
    Command([
        'xacro ', urdf_xacro_file,
        ' robot_ip:=', LaunchConfiguration('robot_ip'),
        ' name:=', LaunchConfiguration('name'),
        ' ur_type:=', LaunchConfiguration('ur_type'),
        ' safety_limits:=', LaunchConfiguration('safety_limits'),
        ' tf_prefix:=', LaunchConfiguration('tf_prefix')
    ]), value_type=str
)

# Build MoveIt configurations
moveit_config = (
    MoveItConfigsBuilder(
        "ur5e", package_name="ur_moveit_config"
    )
    .robot_description(robot_description_arg)
    .robot_description_semantic(file_path='/home/robotik/workspace/ros_ur_driver/src/Universal_Robots_ROS2_Driver/ur_moveit_config/srdf/custom_ur.srdf.xacro')
    .trajectory_execution(file_path='/home/robotik/workspace/ros_ur_driver/src/Universal_Robots_ROS2_Driver/ur_moveit_config/config/controllers.yaml')
    .to_moveit_configs()
)

# Define Move Group Node
move_group_node = Node(
    package="moveit_ros_move_group",
    executable="move_group",
    output="screen",
    parameters=[moveit_config.to_dict(), {"use_sim_time": is_sim}, {"publish_robot_description_semantic": True}],
    arguments=["--ros-args", "--log-level", "info"]
)

# Define RViz Node
rviz_node = Node(
    package="rviz2",
    executable="rviz2",
    name="rviz2",
    output="screen",
    arguments=["-d", os.path.join(get_package_share_directory("ur_moveit_config"), "rviz", "moveit.rviz")],
    parameters=[
        moveit_config.robot_description,
        moveit_config.robot_description_semantic,
        moveit_config.robot_description_kinematics,
        moveit_config.joint_limits
    ]
)

# Launch Description
return LaunchDescription([
    robot_ip_arg,
    name_arg,
    ur_type_arg,
    safety_limits_arg,
    tf_prefix_arg,
    is_sim_arg,
    move_group_node,
    rviz_node
])

'''
